# How to get Hyperlink from whole string

Tags: android

1. I create an application in which i get the response from web service .
2. The response is
   "I might be in danger. I have triggered my panic alarm which is connected to you. Call me now. If i'm not answering, contact the police. My position is:http://maps.google.com/maps?q=21.183783,72.823548"

   3.I store  the string in text view.and i want to open HTTP URL in browser,on the click of text.but how can i get HTTP URL in whole string plese give me idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
var response = "ur response string";
var indexofHttp = response.indexOf('http://');
var url = response.substring(indexofHttp);
```

Comment: var url = response.substring(indexofHttp);

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with php...

If you are able to run php, this should do it.

```
$string = $_GET['string'];
```

OR

```
$string = $_POST['string'];
```

this may change depending on how you get the responce from the website, feel free to send me the form which you get the responce and ill change it accordingly.

```
$string_chunks = explode('http://',$string,2);
$url = 'http://'.$string_chunk['1'];
```

Basically, this will take the string, find the "http://" and create 2 strings out of it. one with the content before the "http://" and one with the content after, which is the url. so it would return $string_chunk['0'] and $string_chunk['1']